# Having trouble displaying a text in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am a nubie in pygame and python overall. I started a simple helicopter game project yesterday but i cant figure out why i cant display a message.

I tried using different code formats and also tried moving a few lines here and there but still could not get it to work.

```py
def display_gameover():
    pygame.font.init()

    font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 100)
    text = font.render("GAME OVER", True, red)
    extRect = text.get_rect()

    screen.blit(text,(screen_height//2, screen_width//2))


    pygame.display.update()

    time.sleep(2)

if  x > screen_width - heli_width or x < 0 or y > screen_height - heli_height or y < 0:
    display_gameover()
    game_loop()
```

I defined `display_gameover` and called it as shown above. However when i try to run the code, everything works fine, apart from the fact that during the 2 second wait time, nothing is displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not sufficient to call `pygame.display.update()`, you've to handle the events, too (e.g. by [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump)).
Further I recommend to use [`pygame.time.wait()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.wait) rather than `time.sleep()`. Be aware that the time unit for `pygame.time.wait()` is milliseconds.

```py
def display_gameover():
    pygame.font.init()

    font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 100)
    text = font.render("GAME OVER", True, red)
    extRect = text.get_rect()

    screen.blit(text,(screen_height//2, screen_width//2))

    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.event.pump()
    pygame.time.wait(2000) # 2000 milliseconds == 2 seconds
```

Furthermore you've to ensure that the Surface which is associated to the display is initialized ([`pygame.display.set_mode()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.set_mode)).
This means if pygame was terminated by `pygame.quit()`, then it has to be reinitialized by `pygame.init()` and `screen` has to be set by `pygame.display.set_mode()` before the call to `display_gameover()`.
Alternatively don't terminate pygame.

Comment: I updated my code with the block of code you provided but it still dosent work.

Comment: Some other part of my code might be causing this(which i doubt it is) but i dont think its possible to post my entire code here.

Comment: Yes i am. But here's  that line of code anyways:screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width,screen_height))

Comment: They look like this :  screen_height = 600
screen_width = 1200

Comment: Do you call `pygame.quit()` somewhere before `display_gameover`?

Comment: Just tried using smaller font size(30), still dosent work

Comment: YES . HERES THE CODE :  for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

Comment: Just tried removing pygame.quit() and quit() , same result , didnt work

Comment: Call `pygyme.init()` respectively `screen = pygame.display.set_mode(...)` in `display_gameover`

Comment: Screen goes black for 2 seconds (instead of text appearing), then game_loop() continues.